# Map from set to its subset

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So I got this question:

> Let $A$ be uncountable infinite set, and let $B$ be a countable subset of $A$. 
> Prove that $A\setminus B$ is uncountable.

So I figured that $A\setminus B\subset A$ and hence $|A\setminus B|\leq|A|$, and all that left to prove is that $|A|\leq|A\setminus B|$

but now I need to find an injective function from $A$ into $A\setminus B$ and I'm having trouble thinking about it.

Comment: Your attempt is to prove that $|A|=|A\setminus B|$, and while it's true, you need to use the axiom of choice for that. The question is asking to prove something weaker: the union of two countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A \setminus B$ were *countable* (i.e. not uncountable).

Then $A = A\setminus B \cup B$ would be countable too as a (disjoint) union of two countable sets. But $A$ is given to be uncountable. Contradiction.

So $A\setminus B$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thank you very much!